# How to configure Facet displays that comes with Commerce kickstart

Tags: 7, views, commerce, search

Commerce kickstart comes with some filtering when viewing all the products, I do not have idea how to make my own facet displays, and I cannot find anything in the drupal configuration about facet displays. Can someone explain it to me?, would be great if it is with an example

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by your "own facet displays" exactly? Are you trying to add new facet filters based on existing fields of your products (e.g. taxonomy terms)?

Comment: yea exactly!! Please tell me how, because I know I can do that with views, but i want to do it in the way its done in commerce kickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I could figured it out thanks to this great tutorial

http://vimeo.com/53404289

There is how you can manage your own commerce facets